# is $f(x,y)=\sqrt{4y^2-9x^2+24y+36x+36}$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

as far as I know, bounded is finite, and by looking the graph of the function, it is infinite. However, it seems to have boundaries which are the points of a hyperbola centered at (2,-3). Any simple explanation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not bounded.

Try $x=0$ and $y\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: so, I could assume that the square root of {16-x^2-y^2} is bounded?

Comment: @wawar05 Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

$f(0,y) \to \infty$ as $y \to \infty$ so the function is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{4(y+3)^2-9(x-2)^2+36} $$
and you can see much better that

- For $|x-2|>2$, $f(x,y)$ is not defined  for $y\approx -3$ as the radicand becomes negative
- At least for $x=0$ or $x=4$, $f(x,y)$ simplifies greatly to $f(x,y)=4|y+3|$, which shows that $f$ is not bounded on its domain. The same happens for any fixed $x$ and $|y|\gg0$, of course

Comment: what about,  the square root of {16-x^2-y^2} , is it bounded as it cannot beyond -4<=x<=4 and 4<=y<=4